# Adding second criteria to np.where in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I currently have a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 200 |  | 10 | Up |
| B | 200 | X | 20 | Up |
| C | 200 |  | 100 |  |
| D | 200 | X | 60 | Up |
| E | 200 | Y | 30 | Up |
| F | 200 |  | 10 | Up |

The comment column was added on using this code:
`df['Comment'] = np.where(df['Column D'] <= 99, 'Up', '')`

What I want to do is add on another criteria so that if Column C is X it returns a different comment and if it is Y it is a different result.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 200 |  | 10 | Up |
| B | 200 | X | 20 | Down |
| C | 200 |  | 100 |  |
| D | 200 | X | 60 | Down |
| E | 200 | Y | 30 | Left |
| F | 200 |  | 10 | Up |

I've tried adding on the different criteria as code in a similar way:

`df['Comment'] = np.where(df['Column D'] <= 99, 'Up', '')`

`df['Comment'] = np.where(df['Column C'] == 'X', 'Down', '')`
etc.

But it rewrites the Comment column each time.
Any help is much apprecoated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `numpy.select` with all your combinations of conditions. However, it seems inefficient if you have many combinations.

Here, I would use boolean indexing and `map`:

```
df.loc[df['Column D'].le(99), 'Comment'] = df['Column C'].map({'': 'Up', 'X': 'Down', 'Y': 'Left'})
```